# Mercenary - usage

Tags: word-usage

Is the usage of mercenary correct here?

> In conclusion, media plays an important role in the welfare of
>   citizens, but it can also be baneful if used as **mercenary**. It is
>   important that it should stay unadulterated because "Without a free
>   and independent media, true democracy is unattainable."

If not, please suggest how can I edit it.

Comment: 1. What are you trying to convey?

2. Are you sure about your choice of 'baneful'?

3. At a purely grammatical level, I think you mean "used as a mercenary" or "they can also be baneful if used as mercentaries".

Comment: I wonder if you mean something such as *In conclusion, the media plays an important role in public welfare, but can be dangerous when used as an attack dog for the elite. It is important that the media should stay unadulterated because "Without a free and independent media, true democracy is unattainable."*

Comment: "Media" is a tricky word to use sometimes, by the way. 'Media' is the plural of 'medium', and fussy users of English use it in the plural. However, sometimes it gets used in the singular (a) because its irregularity and lack of *s* ending makes speakers forget it is plural, and (b) because 'media' or 'the media' are often used as a metonymy for the news and entertainment establishment. To me, 'In conclusion, media plays...' does not read very well.

Comment: @MikeGraham That's what I mean to convey..

Comment: @MikeGraham I'm specifically referring to media of news by 'media'.

Comment: IMO, neither 'baneful' nor 'mercenary' is not a strong choice here -- if you do use 'mercenary', I recommend elaborating on the simile. Otherwise, I think 'tool', 'tool of oppression', 'attack dog', 'weapon', /mouthpiece', etc. could work better.

Comment: Do you mean ".. used as _a_ mercenary" (that is treated as a person who is employed to do a specific job but has no commitment to the cause) or do you mean "...used _in a mercenary manner,"  (that is used to make money for the person using it)? The first treats mercenary as a noun, the second as an adjective.

Comment: Lose “but it can also be baneful if used as mercenary“ and end the sentence after “citizens”. Shorter is better.

Comment: @BoldBen I mean ".. one who works for only money, not for the social cause or for what it should ideally do the work"

Comment: @GlobalCharm good suggestion, but this paragraph is a summary or the conclusion of an essay I have written on "Role of media in democracy". So, I want to add the negative aspect also in it.

Comment: @MikeGraham I too think that these are not a strong choice. I have replaced 'baneful' and 'mercenary' with 'dangerous' and 'attack dog' respectively as these serve my purpose. Thanks 

Comment: @GlobalCharm In that case you need to say "used as _a_ mercenary" because you are using mercenary as a noun. If you leave out the indefinite article 'a' the word turns back into an adjective or adverb.